# Как обьеденить две коллекции mongodb в одну

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

У меня есть две коллекции
configs and points
Коллекция points имеет поле name, в котором хранится идентификатор коллекции конфигов (_id в коллекции configs ).

Как можно объединить две коллекции, учитывая что в коллекции есть массив в котором находятся объекты в которых нужно искать.

configs:

```json
{
    "find": true,
    "points": [{
        "image": true,
        "brand": true,
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "61f0ad909535d94c98056e11"
        },
        "name": "ABC"
    }, {
        "image": true,
        "brand": true,
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "61f0ade99535d94c98056e17"
        },
        "name": "Odido"
    }]
}
```

points

```json
{
    "name": "61f0ad909535d94c98056e11",
    "userID": "61c49f94a02ff82b484cc6d0",
    enter code here
    "create_date": {
        "$date": "2022-01-27T02:53:52.473Z"
    }
}
```

Я хотелбы получить результат похожий на этот

```json
{
    "name": "61f0ad909535d94c98056e11",
    "userID": "61c49f94a02ff82b484cc6d0",
    "config_name": {
        "image": true,
        "brand": true,
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "61f0ad909535d94c98056e11"
        },
        "name": "ABC"
    },
    "create_date": {
        "$date": "2022-01-27T02:53:52.473Z"
    }
}
```

Я пытался исползовать такой запрос, но у меня ничего не вышло

```js
    Points.aggregate([
          {
            $lookup: {
              from: "configs",
              localField: "name",
              foreignField: "_id",
              as: "configs",
            },
          },
        ]);
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
db.points.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { "name": "61f0ad909535d94c98056e11" }
  },
  {
    $set: { "name": { "$toObjectId": "$name" } }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "configs",
      localField: "name",
      foreignField: "points._id",
      as: "config_name"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "config_name": {
        "$first": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": { "$first": "$config_name.points" },
            "as": "item",
            "cond": { "$eq": [ "$name", "$$item._id" ] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]